# Gurobi get name of continuous variable

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

How can I access the attributes of continous gurobi varaibles?

e is initialized via e = mdl.addVars(P, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name = 'e'), and doesn't give me any probelms, like e[1,1].VarName returns "[1,1]", just as expected.

yet the varaible y initialized via
y = mdl.addVars(P, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name = 'y') doesn't work.
here i get the error message

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

when attempting to print out y[1,1].VarName

Answer (score 0):

We can use list comprehension as below:
https://coolnamesfinder.com/biblical-business-names/

```
[var for var in model.getVars() if "gamma" in var.VarName]
```

The above will iterate over all variables. To do it more efficiently such that only the variables  are retrieved, we can do it like below:

```
names_to_retrieve = (f"gamma[{i},{j}]" for i in range(20) for j in range(2))
[model.getVarByName(name) for name in names_to_retrieve]
```

Best regards,

Comment: The link you included does not seem to have anything to do with the post. Please remove it if so.  Also, please check out [Stack Overflow markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting guidance.